# How to prove $\underset{p\leq n}{\prod}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\leq 2n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, products

I know that ($p$ prime)

**(1)** $$\underset{p\leq n}{\prod}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\sim n$$

Is there a way to prove

**(2)** $$\underset{p\leq n}{\prod}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}< 2n$$

?

Thanks!

Comment: Observe that, if for some positive sequence, we have $u_n \sim n$, that is $\dfrac{u_n}{n} \to 1$ then there exists $n_0$ such that  $\dfrac{u_n}{n} <2$ for $n\geq n_0$. Thus, $u_n<2n$, $n\geq n_0$, and your inequality is true for all large $n$.

Comment: Yes, but the "positive sequence" is about prime numbers, does this work even for something like that?

Comment: Yes, $u_n=\underset{p\leq n}{\prod}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}$ is simply the general term of a positive sequence.

Comment: Also for any positive $\epsilon$ we have $\prod p^{1/(p-1)} \leq (1+\epsilon)n$ for sufficiently large n.

Comment: actually, I'm looking for a "well defined" proof of $\underset{p\leq n}{\prod}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}< 2n$, I mean, not a demonstration holding for sufficiently large $n$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a sketch. Using estimates, OlivierOloa's answer should give a proof that avoids the indefinite $n_0.$ The step at (*) is one suggestion (there may be easier ways) and I have omitted the calculation.

In the Wiki entry for Prime Number Theorem there are estimates for the nth prime ascribed in footnotes to Dusart and Bach/Shallit. These bounds are sufficient to show the result you want. For $n\geq 6$ the bounds are:

> $n(\log n+\log\log n-1)\leq p_n\leq n(\log n+\log\log n)$

If we take the log of both sides of $~~\prod_{p\leq n} p^{1/(p-1)}< 2n$ we get

$$\sum_{p\leq n} \frac{\log p}{(p-1)}< \log 2n .$$

The left side only increases at primes so it is enough to consider:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)} \frac{\log p_k}{p_k-1} < \log 2p(\pi(n))=\log 2n.$$

Calling the lower estimate of $p~~ e_l$ and the upper estimate $e_u.$ Then the left side is maximally

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{\log e_u}{e_l-1}. $$

And the r.h.s. is minimally $\log 2e_l$ evaluated at $n = m.$

The first terms in the sum should be computed directly as the estimate is not valid for these.

*It is enough to show that the minimum of estimate for the r.h.s. and the maximum of estimate for the l.h.s. intersect at a certain point (between 5 and 10) and that the respective rates of change mean that the r.h.s will always exceed the l.h.s.

A plot (discrete points joined by lines for clarity) of the two estimates is shown below.

[image]

Then if we exhibit the inequality for the few primes not covered by the estimates we are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really nice! I'd like to ask you a question, but it's not related to this: Is proving a conjecture about prime gaps for sufficiently large $n$, almost the same as proving it completely?

Comment: @Andrea: Almost. For example the prime number thm. gives that there is a prime on $(n,n(1+\epsilon))$ for any $\epsilon>0$ for suff. large $n.$ But to prove a particular $\epsilon $ may require ingenuity. So to make a claim you have to really have to take the extra step. And how big is $n?$

Comment: Uhm, but does that mean it's useless to prove a prime gap for sufficiently large $n$? Because what you wrote already proves it for every gaps for sufficiently large $n$...?

Comment: @Andrea: No not useless at all. In some sense the problem is solved. But there are a lot of proofs that go to great trouble to prove a particular case.

Comment: @Andrea: In the comment I mentioned that in principle we can show it for $n(1+\epsilon)$ for large enough $n$ and a clever technique. So yes, in principle. Also remember that as $\epsilon $ gets small you have an increasing burden for the finite $n< n_0$.

Comment: Sorry for the Off-Topic: remember my limit about Legendre's? I said that it was slowing down, so I thought it would become $<1$ for sufficiently large $n$... I was wrong: yes, it was slowing down, but because that limit exist; I didn't imagine that, I was only thinking about divergence and $<1$: I found out this when I took the log of both sides...I've already edited that attempt showing this, but I'm afraid it would be cancelled if un-deleted, after what happened :P Sorry again, for the OT.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, if for some sequence, we have $u_n \sim n$, that is $\left|\dfrac{u_n}{n}\right| \to 1$ then there exists $n_0$ such that  $\left|\dfrac{u_n}{n}\right| <2$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Thus we have $u_n<2n $ for all large $n$.

You may apply it here with $u_n=\underset{p\leq n}{\prod}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}$.